# Save EventListener in webstorage

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, web-storage

Is it possible to save EventListeners to webstorage?

```
var entity = document.createElement("a");
entity.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    play(path, this.id, "audio");
    e.preventDefault();
});

function save() {
    var playlist = document.getElementById("playlist");
    localStorage.setItem("playlist", playlist.innerHTML);
    localStorage.setItem("id", id);
}
```

This saves the element fine, but when the page is reloaded the listener is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it, since `LocalStorage` can only store strings, and it seems like a bit of overkill to just save an event listener into the `LocalStorage` object, when you don't know that all of your users will even have the capability.

I would consider a pseudo-element storage, [similar to what is discussed here](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/element-datastorage/).

Answer (score 0):

No, it definitely isn't. localStorage only stores strings, period.